# Dynamics CRM 2013 Organization Import Failing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

This is a really crazy one, I know I'm grasping at straw here but while importing a org database into our production environment I'm getting the following error.  Has anyone seen this before?

CrmException System.Net.Socket.SocketException No Such Host is Known
at System.Net.DNS.InternalGetHostByName

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you trying to import Solution or SQL Database? If you are importing database, how you are importing it (e.g. using Management studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Dynamics CRM is setup with SQL Server 2012 High Availability a Listener is required to be used in the connection string. However when doing an Organization import from for example your Test server CRM will not allow you use a Listener if you attempt to use a Listener Dynamics CRM with throw the following error.

> InnerException:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
>   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
>          at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.Utility.ManagedNetworkUtility.IsHostNameLocal(String hostName)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.Utility.ManagedNetworkUtility.AreHostNamesSynonymous(String host1, String host2)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.GrantSrsAccessToConfigDBAction.GrantSrsServiceAccessToLocalConfigDB(Uri reportingUrl)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)

Because Microsoft does not provide a way within its UI to update the connection string back to the physical server name the only option seems to be to manually update the Organization table in the MSCRM_Config database directly, which of course is unsupported by Microsoft.  This has been confirmed by Microsoft Support.

For anyone facing this issue here is Microsoft Supports final answer.

·         Change the Data Source from the SQL Server instance name to the availability group listener name.
The complete connection string should appear similar to the following example, where MSCRMAG is the availability group listener name for the availability group that includes the Microsoft Dynamics CRM configuration database:
Data Source MSCRMAG;Initial Catalog= MSCRM_CONFIG;Integrated Security=SSPI

```
·         Update query for MSCRM_Config DB
Update Organization
set ConnectionString = 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=AG_Listener_Name,Port_Number;Initial Catalog=OrganizationName_MSCRM;Integrated Security=SSPI;multisubnetfailover=true' where DatabaseName = 'OrganizationName_MSCRM'
```

I have discussed this with our senior resources at Microsoft, and we can confirm that this is a workaround for now and the same is supported. The deployment will continue to stay supported until and unless there are no other changes made to the database, then the ones mentioned above.